# Why my page doesnt refresh after deleting a row

Tags: php

My page doesnt refresh after clicking the button delete

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "redcrossqc");
$sql = "DELETE FROM volunteers WHERE volunteer_id = '".$_POST["volunteer_id"]."'";  
if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql))  
{  
  echo 'Data Deleted';  
  echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
}
```

meta http equiv = refresh doesnt seem to refresh.

heres the delete button:

```
<input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete" id="<?php echo $row["volunteer_id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete_data"/>
```

script:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete_data', function(){  
       var volunteer_id = $(this).attr("id");  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"delete.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{volunteer_id:volunteer_id},   
            success:function(data){      
                 $('#volunteer_id').val(data.volunteer_id); 
            }  
       });  
  });
```

Comment: If this code runs through a call from javascript (ajax) then this won't work. The meta tags are only read by the browser on page load. You will need to check for a valid return from the ajax call in javascript and refresh the page there.

Comment: How can you ask a question about a delete button but not post the code for that button?

Comment: Before you post a question, read it back to yourself. Then ask _"Could I answer this questions the way I have asked it? Did I provide enough information?"_

Comment: im sorry i was tired im sorry guys

Comment: just use the ajax to your advantage. If the delete was successful, return some kind of response then refresh the page using `window.location.reload()`

Comment: `$('#volunteer_id').val(data.volunteer_id); `  You seem to be expecting a JSON response, but that's not what you're sending back.

Comment: the delete was successful. Just wanted to refresh the page

Comment: where should i put window.location.reload()?

Comment: Thanks I put the window.location.reload() inside my sucess{}. and now right after deleting a row, the web refreshes. thanks man @Akintunde007 and everyone.

Comment: Do you need to refresh the page though? Why  not just remove the row? I guess the delete button is in the row, so just  select the closest row to that button (in the click callback $(this) is the button), and then hide/remove that row in the success callback. That way you don't have to reload for every change. Or you could hide it on click, and then show it again if the ajax calls fails. makes it react faster, which is nice.

Answer (score 0):

As it was said in some comments, the `meta` tags can only be used if you put them in HTML. But in an ajax request the `meta` tag is not *executed*, the browser doesn't treat the response as if it was a plain old response.

I've updated a little bit your code. I've mainly followed what was said in comment.

As you can see in the comment, your `delete.php` file as a security breach with SQL injection. You should use [prepared statement](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

```
<?php
//delete.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "redcrossqc");
/*
 * You SHOULD use a prepared statement here, you could be victim of
 * SQL injection.
 */
$sql = "DELETE FROM volunteers WHERE volunteer_id = '".$_POST["volunteer_id"]."'";  
mysqli_query($connect, $sql); //Delete but do nothing then.
```

Here your main page, almost everything is the same but after the `success` the page is reload using [`window.location.reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)

```
//yourpage.html
$(document).on('click', '.delete_data', function(){
   var volunteer_id = $(this).attr("id");
   $.ajax({
        url:"delete.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{volunteer_id:volunteer_id},
        success:function(data){
             $('#volunteer_id').val(data.volunteer_id);
             window.location.reload(); //Reload the page on success
        }
   });
```

});